# Best practice for mocking module exports in Typescript & NodeJS

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, typescript, node-modules

We have a NodeJS App written Typescript. 
We use modules to export several functions, not objects.

Once we want to mock these functions during testing, we use `mock-require`

However, the code turns very ugly. As we need to basically

1. import `mock-require`
2. build our mocks and spies
3. `import {functionA,FunctionB} from "module-to-test"`
4. `mock.reRequire("module-to-test")`

---

The code looks kind of like this:

```
// mocking require imports
import * as mock from "mock-require";
import {getMockUserObject} from "../../test/utils/mock-objects";

const user = getMockUserObject();
let userModelSpy;

// mock userModel
userModelSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj("userModelSpy", ["findOne"]);
userModelSpy.findOne.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(user));
mock("../data-source/mongo-data-source", {userModel: userModelSpy});    

// actual import statements
import {functionA,FunctionB} from "module-to-test";

// reRequire the module that we want to test
mock.reRequire("./mail.service");
```

---

Is there any way to make this not as ugly? E.g. keep the imports together. 
If we move the mocking into a beforeEach or generally underneath the import of the actual module-to-test, the reRequire doesn't work or at least our mocks don't get called. So the module-to-test uses the actual dependencies instead of the mocked ones.

Thanks for input!

Answer (score 2):

Mocking can be a pain with ES6 modules and TypeScript has the same issue. I have adopted a different approach: instead of mocking actual imports, I use constructor injection. This way, any mocks can be injected in the tested unit.

Here's an example:

```
import {someDependency} from "./someDependency";

export class Unit {
    private someDependency;
    constructor(someDependency) {
        this.someDependency = someDependency;
    }
}
```

And the unit test:

```
import {Unit} from "./Unit";

const mock: any = () => {};
const unit = new Unit(mock);
```

This way I don't need to have the imports for the dependencies at all in the unit tests.

There are other approaches, but so far, I've found this to be the cleanest.

Note: annotating the mocks with `any` tells TypeScript to allow them in the constructor despite mismatching types.

Comment: Hi mingos. I know this approach from angular. But what if one doesn't want to use classes as it's simply a bunch of functions (e.g. Routers in express). I guess since behind the scenes, classes are just functions as well, there should be a way to also do that.

Comment: I do not know the answer to that. Personally, I integration test controllers rather than unit test them.

Comment: [ts-mock-imports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mock-imports) Is a library I created that allows you to easily mock out class imports. It also plays nice with Typescript so your types are maintained.